# How to send dynamic URL parameter with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I want to send URL (PATH) as `/controller_1/1/` `/controller_2/2/start`

But the parameter #2 of `controller_2` is dynamic.

How to send that parameter?

Answer (score 11):

make the parameter a variable: `/controller_2/${controller2_parameter}/start`

Then you define the value of ${controller2_parameter} wherever and however appropriate: a CSV dataset config, using a regular expression extractor to scrape from a webpage, etc.