# Rest API parameterization using Jmeter

Tags: rest, jmeter

I have one Rest API with the format as 
"https://server name/insecure/client_name/product_id/normalized"
How can I parameterise only client_name and product_id using jmeter and What Sampler should I use.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an external file to parameterize the url

make the parameter a variable: /insecure/${client_name}/product_id/normalized

Then you define the value of ${client_name} wherever and however appropriate: a CSV dataset config, using a regular expression extractor to scrape from a webpage, etc.

i see [older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152838/how-to-send-dynamic-url-parameter-with-jmeter) which might be helpful as well or following blog post [JMeter Parameterization](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide)

Cheers!

Comment: I tried using $(client_name) and $(product_id) but it gets added at last like below "http://server name/insecure/similar/${Client_Name}/${product_id}/normalized?Client_Name=allen_solly&product_id=240337". I want to run the load test for 1000 different product_ids by storing them in an excel. But when I try to parameterise, the parameterised fields are getting added at last.